# Five different games are to be distributed among $4$ children randomly. The probability that each child get at least one game is?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, multinomial-theorem

Here's a question :-
Five different games are to be distributed among 4 children randomly. The probability that each child get at least one game is?

To find the answer, we will have to find the sample space.
Here it is easy to find the sample space using PnC, since each game has an equal chance of being chosen, the sample space becomes $4^5$.
My doubt is why can't we use multinomial theorem for this:-
Let the first child get $x_1$ books, second one get $x_2$ and so on.
So, we may say :-

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 5$$

So, the number of non-negative integral solutions for this equation is:-

$$\binom{5 + 4 -1}{4 - 1}$$

This method gives the wrong answer. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  I assume you meant to say nonnegative integer solutions.

Comment: You can also do this by calculating the probability of the opposite event, and then subtract it from 1. In this case, calculate the probability that 1 specific child will not get any present, then multiply this probability with 4 (since the events are equally probable and mutually exclusive) and subtract the result from 1. This is in general the easiest way to approach such questions, when you try to calculate the probability Y that "at least 1 happens", it is easier to find the probability X that "none happens". Then Y=1-X

Comment: @chris12345  Direct calculation is easier.  Calculating the probability that a distribution of games excludes one or more children requires the use of the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Indeed. But the principle is used by finding Stirling numbers (mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you don't need to calculate the ways in which the events can happen, just the probability. If I choose a specific child to be "team A" and then denote the rest 3 children as "team B", I need to calculate the probability that all presents go to team B, regardless of the distribution inside the team. This calculation is easy to do

Comment: @chris12345 If you are not careful with this then you will count one possibility more than once. Inclusion-Exclusion is requested to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

As @drhab pointed out in a now deleted comment, the formula
$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$
is used when distributing $k$ indistinguishable objects to $n$ distinct boxes.  However, the objects in this problem are distinct.

Also, the outcomes to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 5$ are not equally likely to occur.  There are $\binom{5}{2}3! = 60$ ways to distribute the games to the four children so that the youngest child receives two games, while each of the other children each receive one. On the other hand, there is only one way to distribute all five games to the eldest child.

Since you mentioned, the multinomial theorem, notice that we could express the number of ways of distributing two games to the youngest child and one games each to each of the other children using the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{5}{2, 1, 1, 1} = \frac{5!}{2!1!1!1!}$$
and the number of ways of distributing all five games to the oldest child as
$$\binom{5}{0, 0, 0, 5} = \frac{5!}{0!0!0!5!}$$

As you observed, there are four choices for each of the five games, so there are $4^5$ elements in our sample space.

For the favorable cases, observe that one child must receive two games, while each of the others receives one.  To finish the problem, choose which of the four children receives two games, choose which two of the five games that child receives, and distribute one game each to each of the remaining three children.

> This can be done in $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!$$ ways, so the probability that each child receives at least one game is $$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}3!}{4^5}$$

Comment: Also, i wanted to know if we can always avoid the principle of inclusion and exclusion like here. For example, if we need to find the number of onto functions from one set A with 'm' elements and another set B with 'n' elements, is there a way of finding the answer avoiding the principle of inclusion and exclusion altogether?

Comment: The Inclusion-Exclusion Principle cannot always be avoided, particularly when you are dealing with variable amounts.   For a specific case such as the number of surjective functions from a set with $6$ elements to a set with $4$ elements, you could break the problem down into cases, although this is not practical when the numbers are large.  However, when asked for the number of surjections from a set with $m$ elements to a set with $n$ elements, for variable $m$ and $n$, you need to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote $[n]:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for any positive integer $n$ and $Y^X$ for the set of functions $X\to Y$ in the situation where $X$ and $Y$ are sets.

The question can be rephrased as:

"If $f$ is a randomly chosen element of $[4]^{[5]}$ then what is the probability that it is a surjection?"

A direct answer on that is: $$\frac{4!S(5,4)}{4^5}$$where $S(n,k)$ is used as a notation for [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Here the numerator equals the number of favorable outcomes (surjections $[5]\to[4]$) and the denominator equals the number of possible outcomes (functions $[5]\to[4]$).

Comment: Do you know about a post/blog/video from which i can learn more about Stirling numbers, because i have never actually heard about them?

Comment: Not really something special. But it is not difficult to find that. Just google on "stirling number of the second kind". That will give you enough opportunities to learn more about them.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion-exclusion principle seems the simplest here.

P(each child gets at least one game)

$= \dfrac{4^5- \binom41 3^5 + \binom42 2^5 - \binom43 1^5}{4^5} = \dfrac{15}{64}$

Of course, as drhab says, inclusion-exclusion is involved in Stirlng numbers of the second kind, and using it gives the answer in a jiffy if you have recourse to its tables.